# How to prove that representations on $S^k(V), \bigwedge ^ k(V)$ are irreducible?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Given a $\mathbb{C}$ vector space $V$, let $GL(V)$ act on $\bigotimes^k(V)$ via:

> $GL(V) \times \bigotimes^kV \to \bigotimes^k(V), \ (A,v_1\otimes...\otimes v_k)\mapsto Av_1\otimes...\otimes Av_k.$

I want to show that the representations on symmetric and exterior powers, $S^k(V), \bigwedge^k V$ are irreducible.

I have tried the following:

Consider the representation on $S^k(V).$ Let $\phi:GL(V)\to \mathbb{C}$ be the character corresponding to the representation on $S^k(V).$ Let $\phi_1,...,\phi_h$ be the irreducible characters with multiplicities $n_1,...,n_h$, and $W_1,..,W_h$ be the corresponding representations, i.e. $$S^k(V)=\bigoplus_{i=1}^h n_iW_i \ \mbox{ and } \ \phi=\sum_{i=1}^h n_i\phi_i, $$ where $n_i=(\phi|\phi_i).$ By orthogonality relation on characters, we have : $$(\phi|\phi)=\sum_{i=1}^h n_i ^2.$$ Now, I know from a theorem that $S^k(V) $ is irreducible iff $(\phi|\phi) =1.$ But I don't know how to show this sufficient condition.

I am very new to representation theory. Please help!

Comment: Oh, yes. I was using the usual definition (in case of finite groups) without realizing that it doesn't work here. How can I solve this? Please offer some hint.

Comment: Surely a sum of positive numbers is $1$ if and only if there is only one summand and that summand is itself $1$. So $(\phi,\phi)=1$ iff $\phi$ is irreducible. But how do you plan to use this fact, exactly? If were we talking about the representation of a finite group whose character we knew, then we can explicitly compute the inner product, or even if the group were compact (we could integrate over it instead of summing, thanks to the Haar measure), but general linear groups are not compact. (I am assuming your definition of the inner product is as $\dim\hom_G(V,W)$.)

Comment: What are other sufficient criteria that I could check, as $GL(V)$ is not finite?

Comment: Try restricting these representations to the subgroup $D$ of diagonal matrices.  Any subrepresentation for $GL(V)$ must also be a subrepresentation for $D$.

Comment: I don't think I understood your hint very well. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Is $V$ a vector space over $\Bbb{C}$? The claim is false in characteristic $p$ - that's why I'm asking.

Comment: It's over $\mathbb{C}$, yes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in Nate's comment, the most direct way to do this is probably to consider the decompositions of these representations into common eigenspaces for the subgroup $T$ of diagonal matrices. Thus for each homomorphism $\lambda: T \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^\times$ and each representation $M$ of $G=GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ let
$$M_\lambda=\{m \in M \ | \ tm=\lambda(t)m \ \hbox{for all $t \in T$}\}.$$ The fundamental fact we shall use is that for a module $M$ that is equal to the direct sum
$$M=\bigoplus_\lambda M_\lambda$$ of $T$-weight spaces, every submodule $N$ is also such a direct sum. In fact, if $m=\sum m_\lambda$ with $m_\lambda \in M_\lambda$ and $m \in N$ then each $m_\lambda$ belongs to $N$ as well.

Assuming this fact, the strategy to prove that a given $M$ is irreducible is as follows: suppose $N$ is a non-zero submodule. Then it contains some $T$-eigenvector. Using this $T$-eigenvector, we try to produce all the other $T$-eigenvectors and obtain $N=M$. We will now carry this procedure out.

Let $e_1,\dots,e_n$ be the standard basis of $V=\mathbb{C}^n$, and let $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n:T \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^\times$ be the characters of $T$ corresponding to its diagonal entries, with
$$t e_i=\lambda_i(t) e_i.$$ The $G$-module $\wedge^k V$ is $T$-diagonalizable with
$$t(e_{i_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge e_{i_k})=\lambda_{i_1}(t) \cdots \lambda_{i_k}(t)e_{i_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge e_{i_k}.  $$ This formula shows that the $T$-eigenspaces are all one dimensional, so that if $N$ is a non-zero submodule then it contains some decomposable wedge $e_{i_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge e_{i_k}$. Now given another decomposable wedge $e_{j_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge e_{j_k}$ we can choose a permutation matrix $g$ achieving $g(e_{i_l})=e_{j_l}$ for all $1 \leq l \leq k$. It follows that $N=M$.

The proof for the symmetric power $S^k(V)$ is similar but slightly more complicated. Arguing as above using the fact that for the symmetric powers the $T$-eigenspaces are $1$-dimensional, a non-zero submodule $N$ must contain some monomial
$$e_1^{i_1} \cdots e_n^{i_n}.$$ Assuming $i_j \neq 0$ we apply a matrix $g$ with $g(e_j)=e_j+e_k$ for some $k$ and $g(e_i)=e_i$ for all $i \neq j$. Then expanding $g(e_1^{i_1} \cdots e_n^{i_n})$ as a sum of monomials, one of these is $$e_1^{i_1} \cdots e_j^{i_j-1} \cdots e_k^{i_k+1} \cdots e_n^{i_n}.$$ The fundamental fact with which I began this post shows that $N$ contains all monomials.

(At the last stage, the coefficient of $e_1^{i_1} \cdots e_j^{i_j-1} \cdots e_k^{i_k+1} \cdots e_n^{i_n}$ in the expansion is a binomial coefficient that may be divisble by $p$, so that in characteristic $p$ the argument breaks down precisely here. It seems that the exterior powers and sufficiently small symmetric powers are still irreducible, though.)

Comment: Well done. The weight spaces are 1-dimensional in these cases which makes life a lot simpler.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, Good point! At the moment this important observation is buried in the last sentence of the answer. I should make it more prominent. Also, I will point out where the argument that the symmetric powers are irreducible breaks (as it has to) in characteristic $p$.